# spread values across undefined columns

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of the following structure:

```
   value group1 group2
1:     1      A     a1
2:     2      A     a2
3:     3      A     a3
4:     4      B     b1
5:     5      B     b2
```

I would like to spread it out to this:

```
   group1 var1 var2 var3 value1 value2 value3
1:      A   a1   a2   a3      1      2      3
2:      B   b1   c2   NA      4      5     NA
```

So basically there is an unspecified number of `varX` columns based on the number of unique `group2` in each `group1`, and then an accompanying `valueX` column as well.

Is there a good way to accomplish this? `spread` from tidyr doesn't quite do what I want as I understand it. Thanks!

...

Here you can build the first data.frame:

```
data.frame(value=1:5, group1=c("A","A","A","B","B"), group2=c("a1","a2","a3","b1","b2"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a sequence column, using the development version of `data.table`, this can be done with `rowid` function.  Also, as the `dcast` from `data.table` takes multiple `value.var` columns, it can be done in a single line.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.7+
dcast(setDT(df1), group1~rowid(group1), value.var = c("value", "group2"), sep="")
```

Comment: is that the github version of data.table?

Comment: @moman822 Yes, if you have 1.9.6, create the grouping variable, i.e. `dcast(setDT(df1)[, , rn := 1:.N< , by = group1], group1~rn, value.var = c("value", "group2"))`

Comment: is there an extra comma in the first bracket perhaps?

Comment: @moman822 Yes, that was a typo.  Sorry i.e. `dcast(setDT(df1)[,  rn := 1:.N, by = group1], ..`